# Crystal Reports 2008- distinct count based on condition

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

I have a table that has a column with unique call numbers and another column that has seconds between events. I want to do a distinct count of the call numbers if the seconds between events is greater than 0. I do not see any nulls in this column.

I tried to do a simple Running Total, but it is not counting correctly. I only get a 0 or a 1, not a running total.

[Running Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EugP.jpg)

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEfSE.jpg)

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could also try putting in a formula field that evaluates to or returns  the call number if the event condition is met and base a running total on that field

Comment: what does `sec_entr_disp` column contain?

Comment: What is the intent for the Running Total field?  Are you trying to count how many call numbers have seconds between events > 0?

Comment: It turns out the problem was just placement. When I moved the running totals from the report header to the report footer they started working correctly. Is there a way to make them work in the header?

Comment: R. McMillan, if the sec_entr_disp is 0, the call did not get dispatched, so I am trying to count total calls and dispatched calls.